# Can I re-export default and a named variable from import in one line?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Can I write these 2 lines in one statement?

```js
import standard, { modes } from '../../gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/colors'
export { standard as default, modes }
```

Comment: How about, simply separting by `;` semicolon.

Comment: I've just found that it is `export { default, modes } from '../../gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/colors'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
export { default, modes } from '../../gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/colors'
```

However then `standard` and `modes` won't be available locally.

Comment: yes, I've just found out but you've been very fast, simple question, simple answer, thanks a lot :)